# how to add workgroup in the named.conf.local file

Tags: dns, workgroup

I am new in Linux.  I have found a lot of info here. Thank you for all your works!

I am trying to setup BIND9 in an Ubuntu 20.4 in the office. We don't have DOMAIN in the network. All the Windows PCs are stand alone. They are all under WORKGROUP in Windows setting. And the Ubuntu server has no domain and workgroup too. So I don't really know to how to add the zone in the file named.conf.local The format should like the following. But if it is workgroup instead of domian. what should I do   to make sure the PCs can dynameic register into the DNS server and they can resolve each other?

And in the db.domain configuration file  What should I put then?     Many thanks!!

under named.conf.local

zone "domain" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.domin;
};

Under db.domain configuration file

@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost.